# Skip first nn characters, take the rest with RegEx

Tags: .net, regex

In in Notepad++/pcre/PHP  `\K` resets starting point of match. That ability is not found in the .Net flavor of regex.

How do I go about skipping a specified number of characters?

I created a pattern to do a Replace on `^.{15}`, which eliminates the first 15 characters....Am I on the right track, or is there a better way?

Comment: `Mastering Regular Expressions or Regular Expression Cookbook` Aren't those antiquated books? Why would you think they apply to modern day regular expressions? The `\K` construct is relatively new, it says to not include what's been matched up to this point, while still consuming the text. It's can act as a variable width lookbehind, but it can also be used to just not include a fixed width text as you seek.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Give this a try:

```
(?<=.{15}).+
```

Answer (score 8):

In PCRE, Oniguruma, Boost, ICU regex flavors [`\K` is a kind of a **lookbehind construct**](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlre.html#Look-Around%20Assertions):

> There is a special form of this construct, called `\K` (available since Perl 5.10.0), which causes the regex engine to "keep" everything it had matched prior to the `\K` and not include it in `$&`. ***This effectively provides variable-length look-behind***. The use of `\K` inside of another look-around assertion is allowed, but the behaviour is currently not well defined.

In .NET, `\K` is not necessary since it has [***variable-width (or infinite-width) lookbehind***](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dsy130b4(v=vs.110).aspx#NotExistJustToMakeTheAElementVisible).

> `(?<=subexpression)` is a positive lookbehind assertion; that is, the character or characters before the current position must match *subexpression*.

**To match a digit after the first 15 any characters, use**

```
(?<=^.{15})\d
```

See [demo](http://regexstorm.net/tester?p=(%3F%3C%3D%5E.%7B15%7D)%5Cd&i=1234567890123456)

Do not forget that to make the dot match a newline, you need to use `RegexOptions.Singleline`.

A note from [rexegg.com](http://www.rexegg.com/regex-lookarounds.html#width):

> The only two programming-language flavors that support infinite-width lookbehind are .NET (C#, VB.NET, …) and Matthew Barnett's [regex module](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/regex) for Python.

And as a bonus: your current requirement does not mean you depend on the infinite width lookbehind. Just use a capturing group:

```
var s = Regex.Replace("1234567890123456", @"^(.{15})\d", "$1*");
```

The last `6` will get replaced with `*` and the beginning will get restored in the resulting string using the `$1` backreference.

Comment: Plus one for the extra info.  It helps fill out my understanding.

Answer (score 1):

Technichally those character are not skipped, as they are consumed and considered part of the match. If you would like to skip the characters, then you need a look behind

```
(?<=(.){15})
```